# Error to Connect RabbitMq in hyperic HQ

Tags: rabbitmq, amqp, hyperic

I am trying to monitor a machine in which RabbitMQ is installed.
RabbitMQ's broker is working well in that machine.
Now I want to monitor that machine using open source HypricHQ software.

The problem is the HypricHQ server can't find my RabbitMQ broker.
My Hypric Agent is also working fine, i.e. in HypricHQ server the detail of RabbitMQ machine is showing.

I have checked the error in agent.log file the error logged in that file is:

```
2011-05-30 15:24:16,549 INFO  [Thread-1] [SingleConnectionFactory] Established shared Rabbit Connection: org.springframework.erlang.connection.DefaultConnection@1265109
2011-05-30 15:24:16,574 ERROR [Thread-1] [AutoScan] AutoScan failed for RabbitMQ
org.springframework.erlang.ErlangBadRpcException: {badrpc,{'EXIT',{undef,[{rabbit_access_control,list_vhosts,[]},{rpc,'-handle_call_call/6-fun-0-',5}]}}}
    at org.hyperic.hq.plugin.rabbitmq.core.HypericErlangTemplate.executeRpcAndConvert(HypericErlangTemplate.java:72)
    at org.hyperic.hq.plugin.rabbitmq.core.HypericRabbitAdmin.getVirtualHosts(HypericRabbitAdmin.java:75)
    at org.hyperic.hq.plugin.rabbitmq.detect.RabbitServerDetector.getServerResources(RabbitServerDetector.java:106)
    at org.hyperic.hq.autoinventory.scanimpl.NullScan.scan(NullScan.java:83)
    at org.hyperic.hq.autoinventory.Scanner.start(Scanner.java:198)
    at org.hyperic.hq.autoinventory.ScanManager.mainRunLoop(ScanManager.java:141)
    at org.hyperic.hq.autoinventory.ScanManager.access$000(ScanManager.java:41)
    at org.hyperic.hq.autoinventory.ScanManager$1.run(ScanManager.java:107)
```

Why this error occure?
How can I overcome this error? The OS I am using is Windows 7.

Comment: Is there anything in the RabbitMQ log file?

Comment: There is nothing in RabbitMQ log file i.e. there is no error shown in log file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe it needs your broker to have the rabbitmq-management plugin installed?

Log into the server running the RabbitMQ broker and type

`sudo rabbitmqctl status`

Check that the version is one that is supported by Hypric. A lot of Linux distros have a very old version of RabbitMQ installed. It is easy enough to upgrade using the .deb or .rpm binaries on the RabbitMQ site so you should consider doing that.